# oracle update value with two inner joins

Tags: oracle

Hello i'm trying to update the value of a column in a table with the value of another table with two inner joins.

But my query keeps giving an error, is this even possible with Oracle to update a table with two inner joins.

```
update finaltbl1
(
select table1.old_val, table3.new_val
from
table1
inner join 
table2
on table1.id = table2.id
inner join
table3.name = table2.name
) finaltable1
set
x.old_val = y.new_val
```

Or would it have to be done with a "merge into"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like that:

```
update table1 t1
set old_val = (
   select table3.new_val
   from table2 inner join table3 on table3.name = table2.name 
   where table2.id = t1.id
)
where exists (
   select table3.new_val
   from table2 inner join table3 on table3.name = table2.name 
   where table2.id = t1.id
)
```